# Copying Google Doc text into a google sheet based on the Heading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am a project manager for a construction company. I have a Google doc with a Master To-Do list for different Jobs and subcontractors. https://docs.google.com/document/d/14oVky5DA3xtjE7COMVAx6l26WXb35HvsL8V9dng3eIc/edit?usp=sharing

I want to be able to use a menu item to update a google sheet with items for a specific subcontractor.

So far I can make it find the heading. I'm Not sure how to go about "digging" down into the specific items below it.

I should be able to put it into the appropriate spreadsheet from there. I'm still super new to coding so let me know if I need to clarify anything.

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Update Subs')
  .addItem('Update', 'get_some_heading') //done
  .addToUi();
}
 
 function get_some_heading() {
 var GlobalText = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
 var searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
 var searchSubNames = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4;
 var searchResult = null;
 
 while (searchResult = GlobalText.findElement(searchType, searchResult)) {
   var par = searchResult.getElement().asParagraph();
   var SubName = searchResult.getElement().asParagraph().asText().getText();
   if (par.getHeading() == searchSubNames) {
       if (SubName == "Subcontractor 2"){ 
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert(SubName);
     return SubName;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please elaborate `I'm Not sure how to go about "digging" down into the specific items below it.` What do want to do with the result of "digging" down?

Comment: About `update a google sheet with items for a specific subcontractor`, I cannot understand this from your question. I apologize for this. Can you provide the sample output you expect and explain about the detail of your goal?

Comment: There will be tasks below the contractor's name. The end goal is to send the tasks to a spreadsheet for the corresponding subcontractor. I'm trying to avoid rewriting tasks in multiple locations. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to locate the text that is specific to a given subcontractor. It should help to see the linked google doc.

Comment: In this case, I want the output to be the text of all the tasks under "Subcontractor 2"

Comment: I am sure you have a reason to maintain your task list in a document but it would be much easier to manage in a spreadsheet and then whenever you need the document format generate it from the spreadsheet. A spreadsheet can operate like a poor man's database. the contract group always in the first column for all rows, as many rows as need for tasks. If tasks are subsets of other tasks use a level number in column 2 and then the task details.

Comment: I used to have my to do lists in a spreadsheet but I need to be able to edit them quickly and clearly via mobile. I found the formatting and typing to be unwieldy while in the field. I already figured out how to complete my task from one spreadsheet to another but I was hoping to be able to make it work from the google doc.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve all the content between `Subcontractor 2` and `Subcontractor 3`? How would you like to retrieve that, just a string? Since there's a list, you'd like to retrieve an array with the list items? Could you please clarify all that?